# Failed to generate a private key. Please try again in a few minutes. Firebase doesn't generate new private key for a project

Tags: firebase, api, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I want to generate a new private key from firebase to use the database APIs that firebase provides. When I click on <kbd>get new private key</kbd> to download the private key, I get this message:

> Failed to generate a private key. Please try again in a few minutes.

How should I proceed to get the new private key now?
Why is this happening, Do I have the permissions to download the new private key?
(I am a viewer to the firebase project)

Answer (score 2):

if you create so many service account keys in the past
delete them.

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts
- click the firebase-adminsdk-[some string]@[project name].iam.gserviceaccount.com
- Click keys
- delete all old keys

you should be able to create new keys now

Answer (score 1):

**VIewer** does not have the permission **iam.serviceAccountKeys.create** which is required to create service account keys.

You must add a role to your identity that contains that permission such as **roles/iam.serviceAccountKeyAdmin**

[Service Account Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles)

Comment: Hi John, Thank you so much for replying! I want to start using the APIs available for database management for firebase, and hence wanted to authenticate myself for the same. I saw the authentication required me to download the private key which I couldn't. How do I proceed using IAM?
My deepest apologies since I am a complete beginner

Comment: @AmijeetThakur Create new questions when you have a new question. Do not forget to accept answers that answered your original question.

Answer (score 0):

- Project Viewers don’t have the access to manage the Service Account
  Private keys. This is the reason you got that message when you tried
  to create a private key. As mentioned in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#required_permissions), you
  should have the Service Account Key Admin role
  (roles/iam.serviceAccountKeyAdmin) to manage the Service Account
  keys.
- The Service Account Key Admin role alone is sufficient to create a
  Private Key. But without the Project Viewer Role you won’t be able to
  view the page to create a Private Key from the Firebase Console. So
  please ask the Project Owner or someone who has the access to grant
  IAM Roles on the Project to grant you the Service Account Key Admin
  role in addition to the Project Viewer role.

Answer (score -1):

If your Chrome browser has an update pending, Firebase throws this message. Update your Chrome and retry, it should work.